# Reflection.Emit throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

Im trying to generate a new class/object at runtime.

After reading [How to create a private property using PropertyBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674541/how-to-create-a-private-property-using-propertybuilder), i've managed to get everyting implemented and everything is like i need it.

But as soon as im trying to instanciate my new object, im receiving a `BadImageFormatException`

This seems to be a similar issue, but unresolved [Is there any way to instrument System.Reflection.Emit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269925/is-there-any-way-to-instrument-system-reflection-emit)

Here my code:

**Field:**

```
internal class Field {
      public string FieldName;
      public Type FieldType;
      public string Value;
    }
```

**Generator-Code:**

```
var xx = new List<Field>(new[] { new Field { FieldName = "Name", FieldType = typeof(string), Value = "Hello World" },
        new Field { FieldName = "Id", FieldType = typeof(int), Value = "1" } });
      this.DoVodoo(xx);
```

**The Magic**

```
private dynamic DoVodoo(IEnumerable<Field> fields) {
      var aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");
      var ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

      var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll");

      // Create class with all needed Properties
      var tb = mb.DefineType("ParamRow", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(object));
      foreach (var field in fields) {
        var pb = tb.DefineProperty(field.FieldName, PropertyAttributes.None, CallingConventions.HasThis, field.FieldType, null);

        var getSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
        // Define the "get" accessor method for the Property.
        var custNameGetPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod($"get_{field.FieldName}", getSetAttr, typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);

        var custNameGetIL = custNameGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, custNameGetPropMthdBldr);
        custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Define the "set" accessor method for CustomerName.
        var custNameSetPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod($"set_{field.FieldName}", getSetAttr, null, new[] { typeof(string) });

        var custNameSetIL = custNameSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        //custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, custNameGetPropMthdBldr);
        custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, custNameSetPropMthdBldr);
        custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Last, we must map the two methods created above to our PropertyBuilder to 
        // their corresponding behaviors, "get" and "set" respectively. 
        pb.SetGetMethod(custNameGetPropMthdBldr);
        pb.SetSetMethod(custNameSetPropMthdBldr);
      }

      var finalType = tb.CreateType();

      var result = new List<object>();

      foreach (var field in fields) {
        var inst = ab.CreateInstance(finalType.Name);
        finalType.GetProperty(field.FieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(inst, field.Value); //<-- Here comes the trouble
        result.Add(inst);
      }
      return result;}
```

Any help is appreciated on how to instanciate my newly created Type `ParamRow`.

Bonus-Question:
Why is there an `BadImageFormatException`?

Additional Info:

- .Net-Framework 4.6.1
- Compiler-target is x86
- Never ever did `Reflection.Emit` before

Comment: I'm about to have a look at it in a debugger and see if I can spot the error, but: if you want a good way of avoiding them and getting good error messages, try [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) - it is a wrapper around IL emit (but conceptually the same), and is designed to make it hard to fail (or at least, easy to figure out why it has failed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.Message` of the exception you get is the important bit:

> Field token out of range.

This tells you that it isn't understanding what field you want to use in `ldfld` / `stfld` - which is because you're passing it the *method* token (`custNameGetPropMthdBldr` / `custNameSetPropMthdBldr`) instead of a *field* token.

You need to define and use a field:

```
var fb = tb.DefineField("__" + field.FieldName, field.FieldType, FieldAttributes.Private);
// ...
custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fb);
custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
// ...
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fb);
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Note also that it is more efficient to use the `Type` than the *name* when creating objects via reflection; this works fine:

```
var inst = Activator.CreateInstance(finalType);
```

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. Bit awkward for me, that i've missed the backingfield *-.-

Comment: @lokusking I seem to recall that Sigil would have shown this error at compile time; when calling the method to emit field access, the method signature **demands** that you pass it a field object. It is a great library for making IL easier to get right.

Comment: Usually i'd give it a try, but Company-Policy makes it really hard to get stuff from Nuget. I'll try it at home

Comment: @Marc Gravell, is it compile time error, or a more explicit runtime exception ?